# Error with signal handling for processes in linux

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, unix

The following is the code fragment :

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

sig_atomic_t child1 ;

sig_atomic_t child2 ;

void child1_handler( int sig_num )
{

     int ret ;

 if(sig_num == SIGUSR2 )
 {
    printf("\n Recieved sigusr2 for child1\n");

    ret = kill( getppid() , SIGUSR2 ) ;
    if( ret != 0 )

        kill( getpid() , SIGTERM );
 }
 else if(sig_num == SIGUSR1 )
 { 
    /* child 1 does something */
    printf("\n Recieved sigusr1 for child1\n");
    printf("\n child 1 is doing \n");

    kill( child2 , SIGUSR2 );
 }
}

void child2_handler( int sig_num )
{
if( sig_num == SIGUSR2 )
{
    /* child2 does somethign */
    printf("\n Recieved sigusr2 for child2\n");
    printf("\n child2 is doing \n");

    kill( child1 , SIGUSR2 );

    kill( getpid() , SIGTERM );
}
 }

 void parent_handler( int sig_num )
 {
int ret ;
if( sig_num == SIGUSR2 )
{
    printf("\n Recieved sigusr2 for parent\n");

    ret = kill( child1 , SIGUSR1 ) ;
    if( ret != 0 )
    {
        /* parent does something */

        printf( "\n Parent does something \n" );
        exit(0);
    }
}
   }


   int main()
   {
struct sigaction sa_parent , sa_child1 , sa_child2 ;
pid_t temp_id1 , temp_id2 ;
int temp ;

memset(&sa_parent , 0 , sizeof(sa_parent) ) ;
memset(&sa_child1 , 0 , sizeof(sa_child1) ) ;
memset(&sa_child2 , 0 , sizeof(sa_child2) ) ;

/* parent */

printf( " \n Inside parent \n" );

sa_parent.sa_handler = &parent_handler ;
sigaction( SIGUSR2 , &sa_parent , NULL );

temp_id1 = fork() ;

if( temp_id1 == 0 )
{
    child1 = getpid() ;

    /* child1 */

    printf("\n inside child1 \n" );

    sa_child1.sa_handler = &child1_handler ;    
    sigaction( SIGUSR1 , &sa_child1 , NULL ) ;
    sigaction( SIGUSR2 , &sa_child1 , NULL ) ;

    temp_id2 = fork() ;

    if( temp_id2 == 0 )
    {
        child2 = getpid() ;

        /* child2 */

        printf( "\n inside child2 \n" );

        sa_child2.sa_handler = &child2_handler ;
        sigaction( SIGUSR2 , &sa_child2 , NULL );

        kill( child1 , SIGUSR2 );
    }

    wait(&temp);
}

wait(&temp);
return 0 ;
   }
```

I am expecting the output to depict that first

```
child1 is doing
child2 is doing
parent does something
```

However the output produced is as given below..

```
Inside parent 
inside child1 
inside child2 
Recieved sigusr2 for child1
Recieved sigusr2 for parent
Recieved sigusr1 for child1
child 1 is doing 
Recieved sigusr2 for child1
User defined signal 1

[ what is going wrong ? ]
```

Please ignore the "recieved sign" and "Inside..." lines as they were meant to mark locations in code.

Comment: Why is your code indented in an apparently random fashion?

Comment: You might consider just using sigemptyset() instead of memset(). memset() is not guaranteed to exclude all signals. That's a side note, not quite related to your question, but thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `child1` is not set in the parent process. Therefore, the `kill()` call in the parent will signal all processes in the current process group.

Besides, using `printf()` in a signal handler is rarely safe. It seems almost safe here because the interrupted function is `wait()` which is async-signal-safe but in general it is unsafe.

`waitpid()` or `wait4()` are preferred to `wait()` as they let you wait for a specific child process.

Comment: and similarly, child1 doesn't save child2's pid.

Answer (score 0):

The address spaces of the three processes are not shared in any way.  So the variables 'child1' and 'child2' are distinct between the processes.  So when the first child sets 'child1' it doesn't affect the 'child1' variable in the parent.  So when the parent sends a signal to 'child1' it is sent to 0 -- the entire process group.